# Вертикальный сплит

Tags: visual-studio-code

Студия позволяет делить окно редактора на несколько окон, расположенных горизонтально (слева направо). Знает ли кто-нибуть как сделать сплит окон в редакторе, чтобы окна распологались по вертикали (сверху вниз), т.е. одно окно под другим.

Comment: насколько мне известно, эта функциональность не поддерживается. Есть только вертикальный сплит. Что делать? писать им или перейти на другие редакторы - vim, qt-creator или atom.

Comment: За atom спасибо

Comment: Такого функционала действительно похоже нет, но зачем? Ведь код - это простыня, которая прокручивается сверху вниз! По поводу атома хочу добавить отсебятины - он работает намного медленнее, это чувствуется. И я лично натыкался на пару серьёзных багов, когда не реагировали хоткеи при русской раскладке (этот баг правда уже пофиксили) и когда код на экране перемешивался в нечитаемую кашу при активном использовании фолдинга (до сих пор актуально). В общем, дело ваше конечно, но я считаю, что vscode на порядок качественнее атома.